# How to check if user is locked and how do we unlock that user in Azure AD Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am looking for AZURE AD Graph API to check whether a user is locked and if locked i need to unlock that particular user using Graph API.

Also I have verified the AZURE AD Graph API catalogs mentioned below but i cannot able to find anything related to it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog

Answer (score 5):

You cannot unlock a user account. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-passwords-policy for details of how account lockout duration is calculated by default.

if you have configured smart lockout policies, user remains locked based on the lockout duration specified in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-pass-through-authentication-smart-lockout

Comment: Yes you can :) its tricky...you need a server that is part of the AAD DS domain...an additional user that is member of the Aad DC Administrators (you can add one via Azure Portal) the use the Acitve Directory Users and Computers and reset the password for the user this allows to unlock the account

Comment: @StefanGeorgiev Can you provide information about that? I have a server with Active Directory Users and Computers installed and reset the password from an Admin account is still not possible. Besides, it still is a petition not fulfilled by Microsoft: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e1e4b86-b154-49cd-b9bf-bd832a61f927/unlock-accounts-in-azure-active-directory-domain-services

Comment: @StefanGeorgiev is incorrect. Even with a domain-joined Windows Server, while logged-in as a Domain Administrator, you will still get an "Access Denied" when you try to unlock the account from within the "Active Directory Users and Computers" MMC snap-in.

Answer (score 0):

Others are correct: You cannot unlock an account if you are "pure AzureAD". But I believe you can if you are a hybrid setup, with on-premise AD synching to Azure.