# How to unlock an Azure AD user account using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

First Identify if an Azure AD Account is locked or not and if it is locked then I want to unlock Azure AD Account using Powershell,  I have searched but couldn't find any method or function to do so.
Is it even possible to unlock the Azure AD Account?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you could not unlock the AAD account, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#password-policies-that-only-apply-to-cloud-user-accounts).

As mentioned of how account lockout duration is calculated by default:

> Account lockout
>
> After 10 unsuccessful sign-in attempts with the wrong password, the user is locked out for one minute. Further incorrect sign-in attempts lock out the user for increasing durations of time.

Here is a similar issue, refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444200/how-to-check-if-user-is-locked-and-how-do-we-unlock-that-user-in-azure-ad-graph). Besides, if you want to improve it, you could post your idea in the [AAD feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).